# Create chm file for html files by recursively searching through folders

Tags: python, chm, html-help-workshop

I want to recursively search through folders for html files and generate a chm file for it. While displaying them in chm file the table of contents must be reflecting the folder structure where the html files were present.

I tried HTML Help Workshop for this, but adding each and every file is time taking and the folder structure keeps changing frequently.
In the end I want to run a batch file/python script which will take folder path as input and give chm file as output.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [FAR HTML](https://www.help-info.de/far-html.html) or  other help authoring Tools (to avoid reinventing the wheel).

With FAR HTML you can do anything with your prefered HTML-Editor outside e.g. a paragraph `<a>`  with your folder structure on top of your HTML page and put FAR into your workflow. The Wizard's are great, please see:

[FAR HTML Tour](https://www.help-info.de/far-html-tour.html)

One tip - don't look at all the options of FAR when starting.

1. Put your HTML files to structured subfolders of your project folder e.g.

   welcome.htm
   design.css
   First_Steps\download.htm
   First_Steps\starting_program.htm
   How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm
   How_to_extend\power_function.htm
   images\gui_screenshot.jpg
2. Drag and drop these files to FAR
3. Start the wizard for HTMLHelp 1.x see main menu: Authoring > Help Wizard
4. ready ..